# How to serve response in django then down the server

Tags: python, django

I need a advice 
I want create a path in django for example `/stop-server`
When somebody send a request to `/stop-server` server return a response and then become killed

What's your proposal?.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `os` module to kill the process.

```py
import os

def stop_server(request):
    os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)
```

You can send a response before killing the process.